# How much wage difference between mangaka who published in magazines and on the web?

Tags: manga-production

There are a bunch of manga magazines like:

**Weekly**

- [Weekly Shonen Jump](http://www.shonenjump.com/j/)
- [Weekly Shonen Sunday](http://websunday.net/)
- [Weekly Shonen Magazine](http://www.shonenmagazine.com/)
- **and many more**

**Monthly**

- [Monthly Urasunday](http://urasunday.com/)
- [Ultra Jump](http://ultra.shueisha.co.jp/)
- **and many more**

There is a question about this topic:
[How does a mangaka get paid?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/how-does-a-mangaka-get-paid/38004#38004)

Based on that question, i can assume that the answer was only based on **mangaka that worked for manga magazine**. What about web manga, like Mob Psycho 100? Is there any difference in wages between **mangaka whose works are published in magazines** and **mangaka whose works are published on the web?**

Does the rule "Paid by the total amount of page per chapter" still apply on the web? How many pages do web mangaka have to make for a weekly/monthly serialization?

Related question : [Who started the format 18-36 pages in weekly and 36-60 pages in monthly manga magazine?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43448/who-started-the-format-18-20-pages-in-weekly-and-30-50-pages-in-monthly-manga-ma)