# Is it worth it to support "old"/"out of season" anime?

Tags: anime-production, merchandise, zettai-karen-children

I recently went back through my backlog of anime and watched one show that I ended up falling in love with. It came out in 2007-2008. It's a mediocre/good anime that wasn't popular globally but I regretted not watching it when it aired.

I think the anime staff did put in a lot of effort though and I kinda want to support it even though I'm many years late. I plan to get the Blu-Ray box set and maybe some merchandise. The question is: If I'm this late to support a series, where does my support go to and is it worth it?

P.S. Anime is Zettai Karen Children

Comment: All though we can't really answer `if it's worth it` as this will differ from person to person. You can get some insights regarding where the profits go [How much do mangaka's profit from anime/merchandise sales](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/26730/1458), [Is anime profitable](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/43605/1458) & [how much does a typical anime cost?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4175/1458)

Comment: @Dimitrimx thanks for the links. They're very insightful. My question `if it's worth it` is not really meant for my perspective but for the general purpose of supporting anime/manga in general. I suppose it can be rephrased to `is it productive` or `does anything come out of`.

Answer (score 4):

As long as it is officially sold your purchase will "count".

Maybe you are also interested in knowing that second seasons for older anime do happen. Mushishi got one a decade after the first season. Zettai Karen Children (2008) got The Unlimited - Hyoubu Kyousuke (2013).

The actual staff producing anime most of the time gets a fixed fee to make the anime and will not see money from success or debt from failure. The financial risk is spread among a production committee. This system is the reason for anime being an industry with so much output every year.

Wanting to support contractors is somewhat misguided. The one that takes the risk is the one in need of support. It's also the one who profits from your purchase and has the ability to turn that money into more anime.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not holding out for a second season for multiple factors: One, I know the statistic is something like 5% of anime get a second season and two, many old anime like ZKC don't fit well into the single cour productions that studios nowadays prefer. I might be wrong; Shaman King is coming back after all. I'm watching the Unlimited and will get the BD.

I understand not supporting the contractors part and from @Dimitrimx the best ways are to support the mangaka, get merch and get the BD in that order. Seems I missed the boat as most of that is out of stock everywhere... :(

Comment: The Kiseijuu manga (1989-1995) got an anime adaption in 2014. You never know what is going to happen.